# wsDualHttpBinding and clientBaseAddress with duplex connecton

Tags: wcf

I have seen people use clientBaseAddress at the time of wsDualHttpBinding binding. What is clientBaseAddress.What special meaning it bears.

1) What is the significant of clientBaseAddress ?
2) If I do not provide clientBaseAddress then what problem may occur?

Looking for discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual HTTP binding uses two connections - one from client to server for regular requests and second from server to client for callbacks. The `clientBaseAddress` is used to address where the callback endpoint is listening. This address is send to server so that it can open the connection and call the client back. If you do not specify the address a default is used because it is necessary for dual HTTP binding to work.

Comment: r u trying to say...in Dual HTTP binding always a new connection open when client send a request to service or when service send answer through callback to client. please discuss briefly. thanks

Comment: "Always" is not correct word. Each connection has some lifetime so it can be reused for multiple requests but it is only unidirectional in case of HTTP so client always needs its connection to call the server and server needs different connection to call the client.

Comment: I'm not able to confirm the two connections mentioned in your answer. I have written a small "hello world" wcf service with a callback (and it works), but I can only see one connection established from the client to the server (with tcpview). Is there any official source about two connections being required, and especially about the server connecting to the client please? (or may be there's something I missed in your answer?)

Comment: ok, it seem to be said everywhere that wsDualHttpBinding is not really usable on the internet because of the two connections requirement; however I have still never been able to "see" the second connection in tcpview...