# Accesing wcf service hosted in iis works in localhost but not if accessed by ip:port/service.svc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Web.config

```
<behavior name="JobsServiceBehavior">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<service behaviorConfiguration="JobsServiceBehavior"
           name="XDE.WebServices.Implementation.JobManagerService">
    <endpoint binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
        name="WSDualHttpBinding_IJobManagerService"
        bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttpBinding"
        contract="XDE.CommonInterfaces.Jobs.IJobManagerService" />
</service>
```

app.config

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://192.192.192.1/Services/JobService.svc"
        binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IJobManagerService"
        contract="XDE.CommonInterfaces.Jobs.IJobManagerService"
        name="WSDualHttpBinding_IJobManagerService" />
</client>
```

Hello,
I Have an issue with wcf service. I have a service hosted in an mvc app on iis on a server machine,
when i try to access it nothing happens annd i get a null refrence. I am using DuplexChannelFactory and when i call the open() method nothing happens for a while and then the aplication closes.
This does not happen if I am hosting the mvc app on the same machine as the service consuming app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must discourage you from using wsDualHttpBinding. I had problems with it while using it over the internet and proxies/firewalls. I agree with Juval Lowy's words from his book (Programming WCF Services): "the WSDualHttpBinding is mostly unusable, since it is practically impossible to tunnel through various communication barriers separating the service from the client and the need to find a specific web-server makes this impractical". See also [wsDualHttpBinding ClientBaseAddress & firewalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192453/wsdualhttpbinding-clientbaseaddress-firewalls)
I am strongly suggesting you to use NetTcpBinging/NetTcpRelayBinding (IIS/WAS hosing).

But you can try wsDualHttpBinding. I remember that my problem with it was in **ClientBaseAddress** . AFAIK - **you need to specify it in client config (or programmatically) and use different (extra) port (can be blocked by firewall) in ClientBaseAddress for second http channel to communicate in duplex**